# Streaming image data to SD card using 8-bit data width SDRAM and DCMI peripheral on STM32F446ZCH6

Tags: stm32, camera, sd, stm32cubemx, sdram

I am currently working on an application involving streaming 480p/720p video from an OV5640 camera to an SD card (using SDIO) but I am afraid that the 128Kb of available SRAM are not enough.

Given the situation, in order to increase the available RAM I am trying to interface​ an IS42S16800F-7BLI SDRAM chip with an STM32F446ZCH6 microcontroller on a dedicated PCB but I stumbled across the following problem:

​-Due to the amount of pins used, the STM32 can only communicate with the SDRAM using 8 bits of data

​-I am confused regarding where to connect the DQM pin of the SDRAM when working with 8-bit data width. From what I have read online, it has to be either tied to GND or to the FMC_NBL0 pin but according to STM32CubeIDE, the latter pin is currently used as DCMI_D2 for the DVP camera.

Can someone clarify the process of properly interfacing the DQM pin in the 8 bits mode, or if the external SDRAM is even needed for this task in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone clarify the process of properly interfacing the DQM pin in the 8 bits mode

From https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/dictionary/terms/inputoutput-data-mask-dqm :

"**DQM** :
A control signal, used primarily on SDRAMs, that acts as a mask for reading and writing functions. In some instances, the DQM term includes a prefix "U" or "L" indicating upper or lower byte control. In devices where more than two data bit groupings have a data mask applied, an "x" is applied, where "x" takes the values of a, b, c, etc."

So in your use case, I think you don't even need it and could just be tied to ground.

> if the external SDRAM is even needed for this task in the first place?

**It depends** on how do you want to send the data to the sd card.
Are you going to send the data at each completed HSYNC pulse ? Or at a specified chunk of pixels (by monitoring the pixel clock) ?

Or are you going to send the data frame by frame ?

The latter is impossible since a single frame of 480p at 8-bit color depth is gonna be 307200 Bytes long.